# Liferay : How to Send bulk email automatically on first Sunday of every Month between 8:00 AM to 11:00 AM in interval of 5 minute

Tags: java, cron, liferay, liferay-7

I want to send bulk email after every 5 minute interval on first Sunday of every month between 8:00 AM to 11:00 AM.
what is the best implementation approach to implement this using liferay 7.

**Liferay Version : liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga5**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your post contains two questions at once, about bulk email and scheduling. Please split it into two questions. This will help us to help you, as we can focus on one problem. And please add what you have tried so far to narrow things done. Short questions like "How can I ...." without any further information are often closed as "to broad". Read [ask] to see what I mean.

Comment: I mean how to send bulk email in liferay as background process without user interaction

Comment: Create a scheduler in liferay with cron timing set as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use quartz Job Scheduler
The below cron expression

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 8,9,10,11 ? * SUN#1")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please add more information to your answer, as this might be only a part of the solution. And answers starting with "May be" tend to be closed, as this sounds like a comment, not like a solution. Read [answer] to see what I mean. With a bit more reputation you will be able to post comments as well. And I would guess that you mean `8,9,10`, otherwise the scheduler will fire until 11:55 AM.

Comment: Thanks Vincent Zhou

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following link for setting up scheduled tasks
https://community.liferay.com/es/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-7-ce-liferay-dxp-scheduled-tasks

Is this something related to Newsletter?